# Excel VBA - event change doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba, events

I'm quite new to VBA but so far I'm coming along. Till this moment, where I'm stuck with this challenge.

My goal is to select a percentage (10, 90 or 100) from a drop down menu in a cell in column B, C, D or E and when one of the percentages is selected, I want the same cell to calculate the selected percentage of the value in column A.

So when the cell in column A has a value of "500" and in the same row in Column C I select "90" I want 90 to be replaced with 450 (0.9*500)

The code given here is what I've got so far, including some code already 'borrowed' from another topic. Though it works in a new, clean excel Sheet, it won't work in the document where I want it to work.

Do some of you have any ideas where the flaw can be found?
(I even created a commandbutton with only the task: Application.EnableEvents = True)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo Whoa

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:D")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Value = 90 Then Target.Value = 0.9 * Cells(Target, 1).Value
    ElseIf Target.Value = 10 Then Target.Value = 0.1 * Cells(Target, 1).Value
    ElseIf Target.Value = 100 Then Target.Value = Cells(Target, 1).Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Not a valid percentage"
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Comment: YOu say it doesn't work. What specifically doesn't work? Do you get an error? Unexpected results? Please describe the problem you're having in more detail.

Comment: If you only added this code to a sheet then only changes on that sheet will run your code. Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474356/vba-worksheet-change-event?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want Workbook_SheetChange event. Add your logic to ThisWorkbook in VBA editor.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "Cell changed. Target: " & Target.Worksheet.Name & "!" & Target.Address
End Sub
```

With the above code added to `ThisWorkbook` changes on any sheet in the workbook will trigger the event.

Comment: Hi km1, thanks for the code. This morning I actually found out that when I re-opend the document the code was working just fine. Also I replaced the ElseIf's with just If's. It seems that made things better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA to do what you're asking. Data Validation, and a formula will work:

[image: Data Validation Example]

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for you reaction. I actually do need VBA, because I've got over 40 periods so over 40 columns where the percentage of the costs potentially can come. Therefore I'm trying to avoid using 40 extra columns with formulas. Also the number of rows can easily go over 1000, so to keep the document small, I think just a macro will be better.

Answer (score 0):

meaning you got stopped by an error while application.enableevents=false, and u ran the thing again without application.enableevents=true in between ...

i actually have a button for this issue, just when i'm debugging code, or in the VB editor, Ctrl+G, in the immediate window , you can write application.enableevents=true