# Choose the correct Private Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA Code that works of a Control Button. The code work fine but I would like it to run automatically. I can't seem to get the Private Sub correct. Code is as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim num As String

num = Range("L5").Value

Select Case num

        Case Is = 15, 16, 17, 18, 19

            Range("X5").Value = "510"

        Case Is = 20, 21, 22, 23, 24

            Range("X5").Value = "570"

        Case Is = 25, 26, 27, 28, 29

            Range("X5").Value = "610"

        Case Is = 30, 31, 32, 33, 34

            Range("X5").Value = "630"

        Case Is = 35, 36, 37, 38, 39

            Range("X5").Value = "635"

        Case Is = 40, 41, 42, 43, 44

            Range("X5").Value = "632"

        Case Is = 45, 46, 47, 48, 49

            Range("X5").Value = "622"

        Case Is = 50, 51, 52, 53, 54

            Range("X5").Value = "610"

        Case Is = 55, 56, 57, 58, 59

            Range("X5").Value = "590"

        Case Is = 60, 61, 62, 63, 64

            Range("X5").Value = "565"

        Case Is = 65, 66, 67, 68, 69

            Range("X5").Value = "540"

        Case Is = 70, 71, 72, 73, 74

            Range("X5").Value = "520"

        Case Is = 75, 76, 78, 79

            Range("X5").Value = "490"

        Case Is = 80, 81, 82, 83, 84

            Range("X5").Value = "470"

        Case Is = 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90

            Range("X5").Value = "440"

 End Select

 End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "run automatically"? *When* do you want the code to run?

Comment: So that it runs should Range("L5").Value change without having to press the control button.

Comment: it is unclear what behavior you want. Something has to trigger the code, and you need to explain what you want the trigger to be?

Comment: Move the code to a `Worksheet_change` event handler that monitors the target cell. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10474356/4996248) to see how it works.

Comment: Do you want the values to be text or numbers? When assigning `.Value  = "622"` it puts the text `622` in the cell, not as a number.

Comment: If Range("L5").Value changes Range("X5").Value should 622.

Comment: 622 as the number 622, or the character string "622"? In your posting you are setting character strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Don't need a case statement, you can do it in 1 line of code (plus an if to capture anything outside the range) because your brackets increment in a uniform way:

```
Public Function MyFunction2(ByVal MyValue As Double) As Double
If MyValue < 15 Or MyValue > 90 Then
    MyFunction2 = 0
Else
    MyFunction2 = CDbl(Array(0, 0, 0, 510, 570, 610, 630, 635, 632, 622, 610, 590, 565, 540, 520, 490, 470, 440)(Round(MyValue / 5, 0)))
End Function
```

It's a UDF so follow the same logic as ja72's answer but put MyFunction2 instead of MyFunction, put them side by side so you can compare that they both give the same results.

Comment: Exceptional, Thank you.

Comment: Of course, there is a difference in the results with my answer because a) You use a rounding function `Round()` and I am using a floor function `CLng()`, and b) every time the function is called, the array is allocated which is going to be considerably slower than my answer if this has to happen for lots of cells.

Answer (score 1):

Create a user defined function and use it to update `"X5"` based on the contents of `"L5"`

In a module write the following code:

```
Public Function MyFunction(ByVal value As Double) As Double
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    x = CLng(value)
    Select Case x
        Case 15 To 19
            y = 510
        Case 20 To 24
            y = 570
        Case 25 To 29
            y = 610
        Case 30 To 34
            y = 630
        Case 35 To 39
            y = 635
        Case 40 To 44
            y = 632
        Case 45 To 49
            y = 622
        Case 50 To 54
            y = 610
        Case 55 To 59
            y = 590
        Case 60 To 64
            y = 565
        Case 65 To 69
            y = 540
        Case 70 To 74
            y = 520
        Case 75 To 79
            y = 490
        Case 80 To 84
            y = 470
        Case 85 To 90
            y = 440
        Case Else
            y = 0
    End Select
    MyFunction = CDbl(y)
End Function
```

The result will update automatically.

[image: scr]