# How to Run a Macro if the cell value changes

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro that filters based on a cell value which works fine.

```
Range("A1:L1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Range("U1")
```

I need this macro to run everytime the cell value changes.
I wrote a macro but it is not working i dont get any errors just nothing happens.

I tried:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Tabelle1(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$U$1" Then

Application.EnableEvents = False

Range("A1:L1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Range("U1")

Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

This version should just execute the code and not call a macro. I changed the Worksheet_xxxxx to the sheet name and tried other things.

I also tried:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Arbeitstabelle(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$U$1" Then

Call Macro1

End If
End Sub
```

This version should call the following Macro:

```
Sub Macro1()


Range("A1:L1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Range("U1")

End Sub
```

I put all the Private Sub macros on the Worksheet and the Macro1 in a modul.
The file is .xlsm and doesnt have any problem running other macros so i dont know why its not working. My guess is i probably did something wrong with the names so here are the names:

[image: All Sheets with names]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Worksheet Change Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474356/vba-worksheet-change-event)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640

Comment: @FunThomas I mentioned in the Question where i put the Code its not in a modul

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks i read the answer and changed the Worksheet_Tabelle to Worksheet_change now its working thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been 
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i found another solution

Comment: @Cedric the Intersect function is actually preferable. You'd be able to run the macro if the changed range corresponds with one or more ranges. Consider changing your `If Target.Address...` line.

Answer (score 0):

I changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Arbeitstabelle(ByVal Target As Range)
```

To:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

@Siddharth Rout linked me to:
[Why MS Excel crashes and closes during Worksheet_Change Sub procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640)

Here it is explained  that its not necessary to add the name of the Sheet after `Worksheet_` 
because the code is stored in the sheet so no need to tell it where to do stuff since its not in a module