# Pop up message box when a certain value is entered in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

I have a spreadsheet that I want a message box to pop up if a particular cell is "OH".  Once the message pops up I want to be able to click "OK" and move forward.

Currently I have:

```
Private Sub OH_MSG_Click()

If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Zip Code Entry").Range("State").Value = "OH" Then
  MsgBox "Please review OH Underwriting Guidelines."
End If

End Sub
```

This works if I run in manually, but how can I get it to run automatically as soon as State = OH?

Comment: You can do this by using a change event in the desired sheet. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474356/vba-worksheet-change-event

Comment: Caveat to the previous comment - worksheet change event will not work if the cell changes due to formula recalculation. Can't say whether that's the case here.

Comment: The cell shouldn't change, but other things on the worksheet will change as they continue to work, so I'm thinking if I used a worksheet change event every time they enter something else on the sheet it will pop up which not what they want.  They just want the message to pop up once as a reminder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Microsoft Visual Basic for Apllications in you excel file.
2. Right click of you Worksheet in Pojekt view (on left).
3. Choose Code View. Now will the code window appear.
4. From the top left dropdow nmenu of the Code window choose "Worksheet".
5. From the right drop down menu choose "Change".
   Then place you code (something like this) Example:

> ```
> Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
> If (Target.Address = "$A$2") Then
> If (Range("A2").Value = "OH") Then
> MsgBox "Some message"
> End If
> End If
> End Sub
> ```

That means: If A2 is Selected **AND** any cell in this worksheet hat changed, the macro will check If("A2").Value = "OH") If true will the Msg box Appear if false nothing happend.

Comment: But that means whenever the enter something in any other cell as they work the message will pop up and that's not what they want.  We only want the message to pop up if that particular cell changes and if that particular cell = OH.

Comment: No, Only if A2 is ActiveCell

Comment: I think you meant `Target.Address`, not `ActiveCell.Address`. They're not necessarily the same.

Comment: I entered Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If (ActiveCell.Address = "$C$4") Then if Range.("C4").Value = "OH" Then
MsgBox "Please review OH Underwriting Guidelines"
End If

End Sub, but I keep getting a compile error. Expected:identifier or bracketed expression on the ("C4").

Comment: oh yeah excuse me that's what I mean. I will change the code. Thanks

Comment: @Niki - Try again whit this: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) If (Target.Address = "$C$4") Then If (Range("C4").Value = "OH") Then MsgBox "Some message" End If End If End Sub

Comment: I updated to Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If (Target.Address = "$C$4") Then If (Range("C4").Value = "OH") Then
MsgBox "Please review OH Underwriting Guidelines"
End If

End Sub and I'm still getting a compile error.

Comment: The entire If statement and error is compile error: Syntax Error.

Comment: I got it to work. I had to move some things around.  I had too much on one line!  Thank you for your help!