# Im looking for Excel VBA code to automatically duplicate Tab 1 in workbook when a table in Tab 2 is populated with a name

Tags: excel, vba

VBA code needed:

I have 2 tabs in a workbook. Tab 1 (DIST "A") is a formatted spreadsheet & Tab 2 (RFP) has a table with a column called "Distributor". When I enter names under the Distributor list, could be 1 or 30 differnet names, I want VBA to automatically duplicate Tab 1, rename the duplicated sheet to whatever name I entered, and send it to end of workbook.

Here's my current code, its duplicating the ACTIVE SHEET, Tab 2 and not Tab 1 (what I need)

```
Sub Copyrenameworksheet()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wh = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
If wh.Range("A1").Value <> "" Then
ActiveSheet.Name = wh.Range("A1").Value
End If
wh.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: First step: add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. You declare `ws` and then `Set wh`.

Comment: Next step: Look at the [Worksheet.Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event.

Comment: Thank you, im new to VBA so I still don't understand how to implement this.

Comment: @Gunit Keep reading.  There is quite a bit of documentation around VBA and implementation, e.g., [where to put a change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474356/vba-worksheet-change-event).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from very the nice documentation provided by BigBen, you may look at [Worksheet Change Event tutorial](https://www.thesmallman.com/vba-worksheet-change-events).

It should be a bit easier to understand with this step-by-step introduction.

---

Basically what should be done could be the following:

1. Using 'Intersection' method from the code in the
   tutorial/documentation check whether your list has been changed.
2. Check whether the added worksheet already exists [optional]
3. Duplicate the worksheet and set its name to Target.Value

---

Put the following code into sheet object for 'RFP' worksheet (see the tutorial I linked).
Substitute "A1:A3" range with the range of your distributor list. When you enter new distributor, a message box with the name of the distributor should pop up.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A3")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False


            MsgBox (Target.Value)


        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Now write code that duplicates the worksheet and changes its name to Target.Value and basically all you need to do is to put it instead of MsgBox.