# VBA code needed to duplicate and rename a sheet (Sheet 1) based on cell names in a range on Sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

In this workbook, I have 2 worksheets- (CAM) & (DIST)

On (CAM) is a table titled "Distributor". If I enter a name into this table, I want the (DIST) tab to duplicate and be renamed to what I just entered in the "Distributor" table on sheet 1.

This is code I tried using but..... im not good at this and don't understand very well.

```
Sub AddSheets()

    Dim xRg As Excel.Range
    Dim wSh As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wBk As Excel.Workbook
   Set wSh = ActiveSheet
    Set wBk = ActiveWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xRg In wSh.Range("A1:A7")
    With wBk
        .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = xRg.Value
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
          Debug.Print xRg.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        End With
     Next xRg
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try implementing the Worksheet.Change event as I [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062957/im-looking-for-excel-vba-code-to-automatically-duplicate-tab-1-in-workbook-when#comment106226868_60062957) in your previous question?

Comment: I did....but kept getting errors. I watched the video links and tried researching more but I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your program may work as follows:
1. For each entry in cam, check if a coresponding worksheet exists
2. if not, then create the worksheet by duplicating the dist worksheet:

```
Dim wBk As Workbook
Dim wSh as Worksheet, wNw as Worksheet
Dim xRg as Range
Set wBk = ActiveWorkbook
Set wSh = wBk.Workhseets("CAM")
Set xRg = wSh.Range("B2") ' Assuming your table "CAM" starts in cell B2
while not xRg.Value = ""
   on error resume next
   set wSh = wBk.Worksheets(xRg.Value) ' --- Try accessing worksheet
   on error goto 0                     ' --- Remove error handler
   if wSh is nothing then              ' --- no worksheet
      set sSh = wBk.Worksheets("Dist") ' --- Source worksheet
      set sNw = wBk.Worksheets.Add()   ' --- New worksheet as target
      sSh.UsedRange.Copy               ' --- Copy all from source
      sNw.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
   end if
wend
```

Good luck!